# Can you identify this Bose car amp burned part?

Tags: amplifier, audio, repair

[image: Board with burned part]

Many more pictures [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywyhG.jpg)

The radio and amp stopped working after a battery jumpstart. I fixed the radio by simply changing a fuse but the amp has a burned part. I tried contacting Bose to no avail. I could buy a full new amp but it feels like it would be easy to fix if I could identify the burned part.

A link to the service manual (which I haven't been able to find) would also be very useful.

Comment: Diode? Tantalum capacitor? Either could explode. Looks more diode-like than capacitor-like.

Comment: Unfortunately that shape doesn't immediately point to any particular part.  Try to trace the schematic around it a bit.  That should give us a clue.  Also, explain what caused it to blow.  Did you hook up power backwards, for example?

Comment: @OlinLathrop I suspect that's what happened yes (inverted polarity for a few seconds)

Comment: The square component? Turn the board over. If it has 4 pins it is (was) probably a bridge rectifier. You're on your own guessing the ratings though. Also wosh the black of the PCB and see if there are any clues on the silkscreen.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I will add a pick from the back of the PCB. The image gallery I am linking from already has a pick of the PCB with the black crud removed but no text was revealed on the silkscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean 24V supply during jumpstart? In this case, I suspect the blown part to be a 18V transient voltage suppressor diode. It tries to "short out" voltage in excess of 18V and reverse voltages to protect the electonic behind it. Just removing it should make the amplifier work, but without protection. If it doesn't work with that part removed, there is more damage. If it does, get a new TVS (for example the Littlefuse P6KE18A).

If the voltage was applied in reverse direction, it might be a standard diode, instead of a TVS. Both diodes and (unidirectional) TVS try to kill negative voltage by having a very low impedance (like a short circuit). They loose the fight (diode pulls the voltage down, battery pulls it up) against a car battery in less than a second, and typically get a hard short circuit, which will kill a fuse before the TVS/diode.

Comment: Probably the wires were hooked up to the battery in inverted position for a few seconds. A friend offered to plug the cables from his car and I suspect he plugged them wrong at first.

Comment: With a digital caliper you could quickly evaluate the SMT pads and the charred component size to see if it could indeed be the P6KE18A type TVS as suggested by referencing this data sheet: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/258/SMBJP6KE6.8%28C%29A-SMBJP6KE550%28C%29A%28DO-214AA%29-220730.pdf