# Bose car amp burned part

Tags: amplifier, diodes

My question is a pretty direct follow-up to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/164382/can-you-identify-this-bose-car-amp-burned-part?newreg=2cbf2e5499b34603bec888341db599e3) one. I have what looks to be the same amp, with the same burned part, and it happened after leads were hooked up reverse when jumping my car. The selected answer says it *should* work with the part removed, albeit without reverse-polarity protection. I have some pictures of the part, it kind of split as I removed it, it seemed that there wasn't certainty as to what kind of component it was without further info. I would love to replace the component, but the pads are completely burnt out.

My question is: with the further information about the part (diode?), will the amp work if I put it back in my car, albeit without protection, with the component removed, as assumed before?[image: better diode pic][image]

Comment: Photo of inside is needed. This is most likely reverse polarity protection diode, but it can be verified with eg. designator on the board

Comment: if you post a picture of a small part, then please place it on plain paper, not on grainy wood

Comment: Sorry, fixed the link. Posting new picture in a couple minutes @fifi_22

Comment: Alright, got a better picture @jsotola

Comment: @JerryCoffin fixed the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: with the further information about the part (diode?),
> will the amp work if I put it back in my car, albeit without
> protection, with the component removed, as assumed before?

If it is (was) a reverse protection diode then there is no reason why the amp shouldn't work without it, provided it did its job and the rest of the amp wasn't damaged. However, without that protection the amp is vulnerable to future 'events'. You should replace the diode with one that has a suitable peak current rating, preferably a Schottky type for lowest voltage drop.

In case there *was* other damage, it would be prudent to test the amp with a current limited power supply, a lower rated fuse, or an incandescent lamp in series, to limit current if some other damaged part causes a short circuit.

Comment: How do I realistically replace it if the pads are completely burnt out (see pic I edited in)? I'm handy with a soldering iron and heat gun, but it's just char, even after going at it with alcohol.

Comment: Scrub the area with alcohol and an old toothbrush to get rid of the carbon. If the board is charred then scrape away at it until you see clean fiberglass (imagine you are a dentist cleaning out a cavity). To connect the new part you can either fill the board with epoxy and glue copper foil over where the pads used to be (the neat way) or just run thick copper wires to the part. Scrape the resist off the ground area for one connection, then trace the other pad to its source and join to the nearest good spot. If vias are burned out you can put wires through to join each side.

Comment: Thanks, Bruce! I'll go at it with a bit more elbow grease.